# Angular - Conditional HTTP request inside loop

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I need to be able to loop an array of objects, check a certain property of the object and if it's true, make a HTTP request to get extra data for the object.

Currently, I have written it as I logically thought about it in my head:

```
public refreshParticipants(housingTransactionId: string): Observable<Array<Participant>> {
    const url: string = `${config.apiBaseUrl}`;

    this.authHttpService.get(url)
        .subscribe(response => {
            let participants = response.json().map(p => Participant.createFromResponse(p));

            participants.forEach(participant => {
                if (participant.isBusinessUser) {
                    this.getParticipantBranchFromHousingTransaction(participant.id, housingTransactionId)
                        .subscribe((branch) => {
                            participant.branchId = branch.id;
                        })
                }
                this.participants.push(participant);
            });

            return Observable.of(this.participants);
        });
```

My problem is that the requests aren't being waited for, therefore `this.participants` isn't getting populated.

I'm not sure how to write it so that `this.participants` is populated with both participants who have needed the extra data from the HTTP request and the participants who didn't.

Comment: after set branchId, you can push it to partipants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neater way to achieve what you're trying to do is to use a single observable to resolve the whole set of data:

```
this.authHttpService.get(url).pipe(
    flatMap((response) => {
        let participants = response.json().map(p => participant.createFromResponse(p));             
        let partDataRequests: Observable<Participant>[] = [];
        participants.forEach((participant) => {
            if (participant.isBusinessUser) {
                partDataRequests.push(this.getParticipantBranchFromHousingTransaction(participant.id, housingTransactionId).map((branch) => { participant.branchId = branch.id; return participant; });
            } else {
                partDataRequests.push(of(participant));
            }
        });
        return forkJoin(partDataRequests);
    })
).subscribe((enrichedParticipants) => {
    this.participants = enrichedParticipants;
});
```

(This is assuming rxjs v6, if using rxjs v5, the syntax may be slightly different but the principles would be the same)

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark. This is exactly what I was after even if my question didn't explain it very well. I'm using rxjs v5 but was able to get it to work!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it @Chris. I find that with observables, boiling it down to "how do I make a single observable that represents the whole flow I want" is a good principle to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that your participant is beeing pushed before the subscription has a response. Just move the push line into your subscription.
Like

```
    participants.forEach(participant => {
         if (participant.isBusinessUser) {
             this.getParticipantBranchFromHousingTransaction(participant.id, housingTransactionId)
               .subscribe((branch) => {
                  participant.branchId = branch.id;
                  this.participants.push(participant);
               });
          } else {
            this.participants.push(participant);
          }
    });
```

Comment: This way, I would not get participants who are not "business users". I need all participants but if they are "business users", I need the extra data.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    this.authHttpService.get(url)
        .subscribe(response => {
            let participants = response.json().map(p => Participant.createFromResponse(p));

            participants.forEach(participant => {
                if (participant.isBusinessUser) {
                    // perform a request for extra data
                    this.getParticipantBranchFromHousingTransaction(participant.id, housingTransactionId)
                        .subscribe((branch) => {
                            participant.branchId = branch.id;
                            this.participants.push(participant);
                        })
                }
                else {
                    // this participant does not require extra data
                    this.participants.push(participant);
                }
            });
        })
```

Notice that the array will be finalized, not when the `foreach` loop ends, but when all of the requests get responses.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is inside a method. Please see my updated question - the method returns before the data is populated.